# Maven update only one project at a time

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have several projects on my workspace, and I'm using eclipse for IDE. When I change the pom file one of the projects, maven tries to update the whole projects in my workspace, and It obviously takes a lof of time.

I want update the project whose pom file is chaned only, instead of updating the workpace entirely,

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure m2e is trying to update all of the projects? Are your projects modules of a multi-module-project?

Answer (score 0):

You can close the projects which are not used as of now..